# SQL Server Table is accessible in SSMS but returns error in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

As the title says, I have a database and a table am trying to connect to using vb.net, if I run the select using vb.net it says invalid object name '[table name]
but the same SQL query copy pasted in SSMS runs OK, am going crazy over it. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance
Here is the code

```
Public Sub importVehicles()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection()
    Dim configs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
    If configs.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No settings configured for connection", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        Dim dResult As Integer = Settings.ShowDialog
        If dResult = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim changedConfigs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
            con.ConnectionString = "Server=" & changedConfigs("appServer") & ";Database=" &
                changedConfigs("appDatabase") & ";User=" & changedConfigs("appUser") & ";Pwd=" & changedConfigs("appPass")
        Else
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    Else
        con.ConnectionString = "Server=" & configs("appServer") & ";Database=" &
                configs("appDatabase") & ";User=" & configs("appUser") & ";Pwd=" & configs("appPass")
    End If

    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim sageCmd As New SqlCommand("select * from _btblFAAsset", con)
        Dim sageDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sageCmd)
        Dim sageDs As New DataSet
        sageDa.Fill(sageDs)
        con.Close()

        If Not sageDs.Tables(0).Columns.Contains("ucFARegistrationNumber") And
            Not sageDs.Tables(0).Columns.Contains("ulFAType") And
            Not sageDs.Tables(0).Columns.Contains("uiFACapacity") And
            Not sageDs.Tables(0).Columns.Contains("ucFAMake") Then

            MsgBox("Please add the following user defined fields to Sage before importing, " &
                   "RegistrationNumber as a String of size 200, Capacity of type Integer, Make of type " &
                   "String of size 200, Model of type String size 200 and Type of type look up with " &
                   "options '4x4 and Mini Van'", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation,
                   "Missing Fields")

            Exit Sub
        End If

        openConnection(con)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[_btblFAAsset]", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sageCmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)

        Dim available As New Collection
        For local As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            available.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(local).Item("registration_number"))
        Next
        Dim imported As Integer = 0
        Dim values As New List(Of String)
        For sage As Integer = 0 To sageDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If available.Contains(sageDs.Tables(0).Rows(sage).Item("ucFARegistrationNumber")) Then
                Continue For
            End If
            values.Add("('" & sageDs.Tables(0).Rows(sage).Item("ucFARegistrationNumber") & "', '" &
                       sageDs.Tables(0).Rows(sage).Item("ulFAType") & "', '" &
                       sageDs.Tables(0).Rows(sage).Item("ucFAMake") & "', " &
                       sageDs.Tables(0).Rows(sage).Item("uiFACapacity") & ")")
            imported = imported + 1
        Next
        If values.Count > 0 Then
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vehicles(registration_number, type, model, capacity) VALUES " &
            String.Join(", ", values)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox(imported & " assets successfully imported", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        Else
            MsgBox("No new vehicles fetched, local data is upto date", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
        End If

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If your *code* throws an error, you have to post the code and the full error. Neither VB.NET nor ADO.NET are broken

Comment: All the help you need could be offered if you post your code.

Comment: On which line you get the exception?

Comment: Which part of all that code is the issue, please only post relevant code...

Comment: Debug your code and tell us the value of `con.ConnectionString`

Comment: You are trying to fill the Dataset two times with the same command text. I say 'try' because the second attempt creates a command but never use it. Anyway, put square brackets around the first command table name as well

Comment: ` openConnection(con)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[_btblFAAsset]", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sageCmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)` this is the part that throws an error and the error is "Invalid object name '_btblFAAsset'"

Comment: the thing is if I change table name, the query runs Ok, but for that particular table is when it says invalid object

Comment: @Zaggler I have tried both ways, with/without the square brackets but the problem still persists

Comment: Does your first query work in the code you provided. It should hit that first.. Which is the same table... But you said the other query with brackets is the problem... Remove the dbo part are you sure the table is under dbo?

Comment: actually its the first query that doesn't run, the first select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to look at:

1. Make sure that the Database that you are *actually* connecting to has the table.
2. If the table exists in only one Schema, then Schema-qualify the table name in the first query, just like you are doing in the second query (i.e. `dbo._btblFAAsset`).
3. Or, if this table exists as the same name in multiple Schemas, then you need to check the SQL Server Login that you are connecting as, including what the Login's default Schema is (since that is where it will look for objects).
4. Make sure you are executing the correct SqlCommand. I'm not sure what the intention is for the second command, but it does at least *seem* odd to create a new SqlCommand object and then execute the first one:

   ```vb
   Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[_btblFAAsset]", con)
   Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sageCmd)
   ```

   As you can see, you create `cmd` yet pass the original `sageCmd` into the `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Yea thanks, I saw that and I rectified it and it worked (the cmd and sageCmd mixing)